# Why didn't I get MySQL as possible database type to use for the site?

Tags: 7, installation

When I installed Drupal 7 on localhost, it didn't show MySQL as database type.

> [image: pic to show error]

Why?

It also shows this error.

> Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY' in D:\AppServ\www\drupal\includes\database\mysql\database.inc on line 46

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Appserv](http://www.appservnetwork.com/) includes MySql, but your post shows that only SQLite is installed

Try to reinstall Appserv with MySQL

There is more discussion on this error on [drupal.org](https://drupal.org/node/988326)

You may need to enable PDO example:

> use the phpinfo() function to know the path of php.ini: "Loaded Configuration File    C:\Windows\php.ini", then modify the php.ini file to enable: "extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll" and it works!

Answer (score 2):

You need the php's PDO and mysql extensions installed on your system in order for Drupal to use MySql data storage. One or both of them are apparently missing, and Drupal defaults to Sqlite, which is a simple database system and only needs a writable file to work. Please refer to [Drupal's system requirements page](https://drupal.org/requirements) for further info.

Comment: ok how can i install mysql , i install appserv

Comment: Sorry, I know nothing about AppServ. Perhaps reading [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231676/how-to-enable-pdo-on-appserv-on-windows) may be of help